# DIV within flex container pushing down entire row

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm working on an angular/js app using directives and this particular flex-container uses divs(directives) which may contain one or more items.  When a directive includes 3 items for the flexbox, if it isn't a perfect fit for all items in that directive, it pushes the entire row down instead of say leaving one on the top line and putting the rest on the 2nd line.  It will instead leave an empty space on top and push all 3 to the 2nd line.  The reason for directives in this case is for reuse and grouping common functionality together.

To simplify, this demonstrates the issue I'm seeing just with using divs.  Looking at the example if you resize the window you'll see that as soon as there is not enough room to fit the 6th bubble, all 3 in that div get pushed to the second row.
[example on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OKJGpP)

```css
dl,
dt,
dd {
  /* resetting definition list styling */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bubble {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: rgb(52, 58, 64);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

.flex-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container div {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <dl class="bubble">1</dl>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dl class="bubble">2</dl>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dl class="bubble">3</dl>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dl class="bubble">4</dl>
    <dl class="bubble">5</dl>
    <dl class="bubble">6</dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible for me to get that div with 3 items to start after the 3rd bubble and wrap only those that don't fit to the second line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update:

Use

```
.flex-container div {
  display: contents;
}
```

Instead of

```
.flex-container div {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

display: contents basically ignores the element and makes the element's parent, or flex-container in this case, the parent of the children or the dl tags here. This only affects the layout. The children still keep any of the styling inherited from their wrapper element.

Comment: The issue is the directives render a div, i can't seem to avoid a div within my flex container unless i don't use the directive.  Otherwise, any of my directives that contain just one element works fine.

Comment: I did .flex-container div  {
   display: contents;
} and kept everything else the same, and it seems to be doing what you want.

Comment: Yep, that works!  Now let's hope that plays nice with my more involved dashboard and directives but that seemed to be my root issue.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Showing Roya's suggestion here which does the trick...

```
        dl, dt, dd {
        /* resetting definition list styling */
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .bubble {
        display: block;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        background: rgb(52, 58, 64);
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 1rem;
        width: 10rem;
        height: 10rem;
        margin-right: 2rem;
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }

    .flex-container {
        display: inline-flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .flex-container div {
        display: contents;
    }

    <div class="flex-container">
      <div><dl class="bubble">1</dl></div>
      <div><dl class="bubble">2</dl></div>
      <div><dl class="bubble">3</dl></div>
      <div><dl class="bubble">4</dl></div>
      <div>
        <dl class="bubble">5</dl>
        <dl class="bubble">6</dl>
        <dl class="bubble">7</dl>
      </div>
    </div>
```